# Deploying Blazor Web app .net 8 in a subfolder - error of type mapping

Tags: iis, blazor, subdirectory, .net-8.0

I've created a new Blazor Web App project (.Net 8) and would like to deploy it in IIS on windows server but in a subfolder "MyApp".
For this I've updated the app.razor file by adding :

```
<base href="/MyApp/" />
```

Everything works fine, except when I go to the "Manage your account" page and try to browse the menu.
When I first go to "Manage your account" it redirects me to

https://example.com/MyApp/Account/Manage

Then I can go to "Email" which redirects me to :

https://example.com/MyApp/Account/Manage/Email

But then when I go to "Password", it doesn't redirect me correctly, instead the URL used is:

https://example.com/MyApp/Account/Manage/Account/Manage/ChangePassword

And I can't resolve this double "Account/Manage/Account/Manage" issue.

Should I add something else in my program.cs file ?

Comment: How did you configure your webiste? Are Manage and Email subfolders of the project? Is ChangePassword also a subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the missing part to make it work properly.
There are 2 steps to be done:

- As said in my question, the `<base href="/MyApp/">` must be added in the app.razor file
- And in program.cs file in the server project a code like this must be added:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/MyApp"), first =>
    {
        first.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/MyApp);
        first.UseStaticFiles();
        first.UseRouting();
    });
}
```

I managed to deploy like this on IIS.